# Сохранение даты в базе Oracle

Tags: php, yii2, oracle

Как верно сохранить дату в бд Oracle с использованием yii2?

В Оракловской таблице поле дата в  фомате дата.

Модель

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['DATE'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['DATE'],
            ],
            'value' => new Expression("TO_DATE('"
           //$this->DATE
        .Yii::$app->session->get('DATE')
            ."','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Контроллер
в действиях создания и редактирования 
использую запись в ссесию так как не выходит получить через $this->DATE в моделе.

```
Yii::$app->session->set('DATE', $date );
```

Вопрос как без использования сессионного костыля верно сохранить дату введенную пользователем.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, можно установить используемый формат даты для коннекта.
Во-вторых, можно доработать beforeSave и afterSave для автоматического конвертирования
В-третьих, это достаточно полно описано тут: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6004

Цитирую пример кода по ссылке:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

class ActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    private $dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss';

   public function dates()
    {
        return ['DT_EVENT'];
    }
    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if(parent::beforeSave($insert)){
            foreach($this->dates() as $attribute){
                $this->$attribute = new Expression("to_date('" . $this->$attribute . "','{$this->dateFormat}')");
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        // restore dates
        foreach($this->dates() as $attribute){
            $this->$attribute = str_replace(array("to_date('", "','{$this->dateFormat}')"), '', $this->$attribute->expression);
        }
    }
}
```